# Given the power series, for all $c > 0 $ the power series either converges diverges or both, for at atleast one $x>0$, what is true?

Tags: power-series, divergent-series

Let $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{c^nx^n}{n}$ be a power series.

I tried solving using the ratio test

$|\frac{U_n+1}{U_n}|= |\frac{c^{n+1} x^{n+1}}{n+1} \frac{n}{c^nx^n}|= |cx| =\lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{1}{1+{\frac{1}{n}}} = L =  |cx|$

According to ratio test I get :

1.) converges for $|cx| < 1= |x|<\frac{1}{|c|}$

2.) diverges for $|cx| > 1= |x|>\frac{1}{|c|}$

3.) $|cx| = 1 ?$ confirm that in the next step, by checking wheather it's converging at endpoints or not.

so now checking whether series, it's convergent at the endpoints so for $ x = \frac{1}{c}$ and $x=\frac{-1}{c}$.

The result :

At $ x = \frac{1}{c}$
,  $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{c^n{c}^{-n}}{n}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  \frac{1}{n}$ diverges through p test.

At $ x = \frac{-1}{c}$
,
$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{c^n{-c}^{-n}}{n}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{-1^{n}}{n}$ converges through alternating test

so I can conclude that :

1.) convergent for $x \in [\frac{-1}{c}, \frac{1}{c})$. But statement 1 says " for all c >0  power series converges for atleast one x > 0" is this true?

- rewrite like $x \in (0, \frac{1}{c}) ==  0<x< \frac{1}{c}$

2.) and divergent for other x values,otherwise. But statement 2 says " for all c >0  power series diverges for atleast one x > 0" is this true?

-suppose for example I take c = 300.

so, I know x converges for $ x \in (0, \frac{1}{300})$ taking $x = \frac{1}{500}=0.02 > 0 $, which is part of the set.

and diverges for all $ x ≥ \frac{1}{300}>0$

-statement 1 says " for all c >0  power series converges for atleast one x > 0" is this true?

-statement 2 says " for all c >0  power series diverges for atleast one x > 0" is this true?

so is both statements or either statements true?

My answer - I feel  both statements should be true

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The construction "for all $c > 0$ the ... for at least one $x$ ..." means that we are allowed to specify $x$ dependent on $c$.  (This is because $c$ is (universally) quantified before $x$ is (existentially) quantified.)  It is sufficient to show, for each possible choice of $c$ that there is a choice of $x$ (which is permitted to depend on $c$) satisfying the part of the sentence that is suppressed in the quote above.

For 1, why not observe that for $c > 0$, one may take $x = \frac{1}{2c}$, which is positive and which satisfies
$$  \frac{1}{2c} \in \left[\frac{-1}{|c|}, \frac{1}{|c|} \right)  \text{.}  $$
You're only required to show (for each choice of $c$) *one* positive $x$ for which the series converges, so pick any one in the positive half of the interval.  Notice that we have exhibited "for each $c > 0$ a specific $x > 0$ where the series converges".

Likewise, for 2, you only have to exhibit *one* positive $x$ for each choice of $c$.  Why not $x = 2/|c|$?  Notice that we have exhibited "for each $c > 0$ a specific $x > 0$ where the series diverges".

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. yeah taking $x = \frac {1}{2c}$ and $ x = \frac{2}{|c|}$. makes sense. dependence is also making sense.